# simple css question regarding text align

Tags: css

I'm making a menu. Looks something like thing:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a>menu/<br/>item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to center the text vertically. I usually go with

```
ul li { height: 50px; line-height: 50px; }
```

for example. But obviously this does not work since it is a 
 tag in the menu. I need the text to look like

```
menu/
item
```

in the menu. Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: display as a table-cell is a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set a smaller line height and equal padding top and bottom, like so:

```
ul li {
   padding: 20px 0;
   line-height: 14px;
}
```

This method assumes each item list contains two lines of text for them all to be equal height.

It would look something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/ajcw/fVamh/

Comment: Thanks, but forgot to mention that some are 1 line. However, i added a class to the dual-rows with jquery and changed the padding. I guess it works ok..

Answer (score 1):

Vertical Align is only supported in table cells. You can either adjust your padding to move the text around (will only work for your particular font size and if that changes you will have to re-adjust your padding), or as Dan Andrews mentioned above, you can use `display: table-cell`, however, this is only supported by the newer browsers, so depending on your audience, it may not be a viable solution.

For table-cell support, see [QuirksMode.com](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)